# Need help in ios 7 Keychain add and retrieve Public Key kSecReturnRef

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, keychain

In iOS7, when I add a RSA Public Key in the Keychain, it is successfully added but if I want to retrieve "kSecReturnRef", I get nil as result, but if I retrieve "kSecReturnPersistentRef" or "kSecReturnData" it is working fine.
This problem only occurs if I add a RSA public key via "SecItemAdd()" method.
Everything is good if I generate a public key via "SecKeyGeneratePair()" and retrieve "kSecReturnRef".

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Download the sample code "CryptoExercise"
2. Call method "addPeerPublicKey:keyBits:"
3. Pass a public key data and name
4. Above method internally calls "getKeyRefWithPersistentKeyRef", and this method returns nil value for "SecKeyRef".

This problem is only in iOS 7 whereas the same code works just fine from iOS3 to  iOS6.

Expected Results:

```
< SecKeyRef algorithm id: 1, key type: RSAPublicKey, version: 2, block size: 512 bits, exponent: {hex: 10001, decimal: 65537}, modulus: AE098BC28358D88AE7602E8BB91007239018D40BB1A87F2245199A208CA21B8EFCFFE2373B470E6075D740AC1A25CD7914A6BA5680701DFB9428E2DD461965B7, addr: 0x9abe600 >
```

Actual Results:

```
< nil>
```

Sample Code: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008019-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Any help would be appreciated.